# Can I prevent the DeleteProfileScorable from being registered in my bot?

Tags: c#, autofac, botframework

The Bot Framework BotBuilder SDK includes a scorable called [DeleteProfileScorable](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/DeleteProfileScorable.cs), which will intercept a message with the text "/deleteprofile" and runs the following logic to clear the user's profile:

```
    protected override async Task PostAsync(IActivity item, string state, CancellationToken token)
    {
        this.stack.Reset();
        botData.UserData.Clear();
        botData.PrivateConversationData.Clear();
        await botData.FlushAsync(token);
        await botToUser.PostAsync(Resources.UserProfileDeleted);
    }
```

I'm not intentionally registering this Scorable specifically in my bot, but it appears that it's being registered by way of the Autofac [DialogModule](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/31048a2173313c81a2db47efce6a8a869b4ec284/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Autofac/Dialogs/DialogModule.cs) and it activates when I send "/deleteprofile". I don't want this functionality available in my production app - is there any way to suppress its registering or functioning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing AutoFac registrations involves re-creating the container, and not adding the registrations not used.  It seems, for this case, it is more trivial to just override the '/deleteprofile' registration with one that will never be used.  Something like:

```
Conversation.UpdateContainer(b =>
{
    b
    .Register(c => new Regex("(?!x)x", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace))
    .Keyed<Regex>(DialogModule.Key_DeleteProfile_Regex)
    .SingleInstance();                
});
```

With the above addition to Global.asax.cs Applicaiton_Start method, the delete profile scorable still exists, but no text will ever match the RegEx: so it is effectively disabled.

Comment: That makes sense - I agree that rebuilding the container seems like overkill since this will work. Thanks for the answer!